# I have 2 GRUBs on different HDD. How to make one common?

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, grub

So, I had dual boot system : Window 8 and Arch (both on the `/dev/sda`, but different partition). As far as I know, grub was installed on the partition with Arch, because I added *windows boot loader partition* after via *os-prober*.

Today I've installed other Linux distro on the `/dev/sdb` using manual install. As far as I know, grub from the latest Linux installation will be used instead of old one. I checked it with **Boot Info Script** and it told me that grub is installed on `/dev/sdb`. I don't want to load from the grub from the 2nd HDD (`/dev/sdb`). Instead, I want to load from grub, which is installed with Arch which is on `/dev/sda`.

**Summing up:**
1. I'll need to add distro from the `/dev/sdb` via *os-prober* on the `/dev/sda` to make grub recognize new distro.
2. How to switch off the grub from the 2nd HDD and switch on the old one?

P.S. New Grub is working fine and recognize all OSes I have, but I just want to use the old one.

Comment: Boot to your Arch installation and reinstall grub from there (using something like `grub-install --boot-directory=/boot /dev/sda` as root). I'm assuming MBR and Legacy Boot here. UEFI, Secure Boot, and GPT make things a little trickier.

Comment: ``parted -l`` says /dev/sda 's partition table is gpt and /dev/sdb 's is msdos.

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://askubuntu.com/questions/281735/how-to-boot-over-multiple-drives-on-a-uefi-motherboard-using-grub2

Comment: @MariusMatutiae, the question is not about the posibility to boot from all OSes, bc I can do it. My question is about how to change a newly installed grub in favor of old one.